# Certain fonts missing from xlsfonts in Centos 6.4

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

I have a certain software on CentOS 6.4 that gave the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  45 (X_OpenFont)
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Running `strace` shows that the error happens just about here:

```
writev(4, [{"-\2\21\0\4\0\240\0027\0\240\2-adobe-helvetica-bol"..., ...
```

I thought some fonts were missing from my system, so I went on to insall all xorg-x11-fonts-* packages on my system. The Adobe fonts should be included in the xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi package.

I thought the fonts may not be in the fonts path, so I ran `xset q`. The fonts seemed to be in the X font path.

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Shift Lock:  off    04: Group 2:     off    05: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  65535    repeat rate:  0
  auto repeating keys:  00feffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffffffdfe5ef
                        ffffffffffffffff
                        ffffffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x50    BlackPixel:  0    WhitePixel:  16777215
Font Path:
  /usr/NX/share/fonts/TTF,/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF/,/usr/NX/share/fonts/base,/usr/NX/share/fonts/base,/usr/NX/share/fonts/base
Bug Mode: compatibility mode is disabled
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

Despite all these, the font required (any font from the Adobe family) seems not to be reported with `xlsfonts`, and the application error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with fonts on Linux can be annoying. I usually use the tool `fontmatrix`. To install it:

```
$ sudo yum install fontmatrix
```

#### Example

```
$ fontmatrix
```

[image: ss of fontmatrix]

[image: ss of tree1]    [image: ss of tree2]

Using this tool you can also import fonts, preview them, and pretty much do anything you need to when dealing with fonts.